# Ogg music files glitch in Banshee

Tags: banshee, gstreamer, ogg-vorbis, audacity

I have a music library of mainly `ogg` files.  I recently moved to a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04.  I've tried playing these `ogg` files in Banshee (and Rhythmbox) but every 20s or so there is a glitch in the music.  It feels like a skip except it doesn't move the read head.  The music can be played without error when imported into Audacity and I have not noticed this glitch in Banshee with any of my `mp3` files.

I would like to know what Audacity is doing right that Banshee (and Rhythmbox) are doing wrong.  I would also ideally want to know how to fix this without reripping my entire library into `mp3` or relying on Audacity as a media player.

Comment: At least conceptually, when you play music in Banshee GStreamer has to run the Ogg decoder in real time. Delays in real-time decoding will cause brief pauses in playback. When you open the file in Audacity the whole file is decoded as the file is opened. Delays in decoding here will only cause Audacity to take slightly longer to open the file.

Comment: I've noticed that gstreamer and VLC are prone to skipping where mplayer does not ; while I've never heard it with Ogg Vorbis files (encoded at rates 5 or 6), I've heard it on WMA. See : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=599877 ; I wonder if this is to do with timestamps as in the linked bug (I can't find my original bug..)

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards